# CakePHP 2.6 virtual host apache2 linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, cakephp

I want to setup cakePHP on my apache

my apache.conf file

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName campusjaeger.dev
        ServerAlias campusjaeger.dev
        DocumentRoot /home/insasse/campusjaeger/cakephp/app/webroot
        AccessFileName .htlocal .htdefault .htaccess
        <Directory "/home/insasse/campusjaeger/cakephp/app/webroot">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But instead of loading the index.php under the webroot it calls the index.php under /var/www/html/ ... What am I doing wrong?

My tail access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:57 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "http://campusjaeger.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3524 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3623 "http://campusjaeger.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "http://campusjaeger.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3524 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3623 "http://campusjaeger.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "http://campusjaeger.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3524 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3623 "http://campusjaeger.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Feb/2017:14:21:58 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "http://campusjaeger.dev/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36"
```

my tail error.log

```
[Tue Feb 14 14:10:08.333823 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16084] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 14 14:10:09.501924 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16577] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 14 14:10:09.501989 2017] [core:notice] [pid 16577] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Feb 14 14:17:21.337819 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16577] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 14 14:17:22.476980 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17035] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 14 14:17:22.477040 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17035] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Feb 14 14:19:38.505825 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17035] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 14 14:19:39.648414 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17248] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 14 14:19:39.648478 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17248] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: You have no `ServerName` configured. Most likely the default host is responding, not that virtual one.

Comment: thanks added a servername but still no difference and i did a reload.

Comment: So what request URL are you trying?

Comment: After restarting the http server process please do a _deep_ reload in your browser (CTRL-SHIFT-R or similar) or clear your browsers cache. You are probbly looking at a cached file.

Comment: Please check your http servers access and error log file when reloading. What is appended there?

Comment: Hm... And you say that file that is delivered is _not_ the index file in the configured folder? Then most likely that configuration section is ignored... I suggest you place a definite syntax error in that section and again restart the http server. Do you get errors in the log file or not?

Comment: Ah .... I forgot to make a 

`sudo a2ensite` 

Thanks for your help your last comment reminds me on this.

Comment: Happens to all of us :-) Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to do a `sudo a2ensite my_vhost.conf`

Hope that helps someone ,too.